# how to determine duplicate rows where not all are the same in a column?

Tags: r, dataframe

suppose I want to find duplicate rows for columns:

```
              cols<-c("col1", "col2")
```

I know for data f4 duplicate rows are:

```
      Jo<-df4[duplicated(df4[cols]) | duplicated(df4[cols], fromLast = TRUE), ]
```

and removing these duplicate rows from data set is given:

```
      No<-df4[!(duplicated(df4[cols]) | duplicated(df4[cols], fromLast = TRUE)), ]
```

I want to modify the above codes. Suppose there is a column called mode. It takes integers between 1 to 4. I don't want all of duplicate rows have the same mode==2.

example

```
          col1       col2        mode
            1          3           5
            5          3           9
            1          2           1
            1          2           1
            3          2           2
            3          2           2
            4          1           3
            4          1           2
            4          1           2
```

output

```
          Jo:

          col1       col2        mode
            1          2           1
            1          2           1
            4          1           3
            4          1           2
            4          1           2

          No:

          col1       col2        mode
            1          3           5
            5          3           9
            3          2           2
            3          2           2
```

in the above example in 3 and 4-th rows since mode==2 for both it is not duplicate but for three last row since one of them is not 2 , the are duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the updated dataset,

```
library(dplyr)
out1 <- df2 %>%
            group_by_at(vars(cols)) %>%
            filter(n() > 1, !all(mode ==2)) 


out2 <- anti_join(df2, out1)
out1
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   col1, col2 [2]
#   col1  col2  mode
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     1
#2     1     2     1
#3     4     1     3
#4     4     1     2
#5     4     1     2

out2
#  col1 col2 mode
#1    1    3    5
#2    5    3    9
#3    3    2    2
#4    3    2    2
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df2)[ ,  .I[.N > 1 & !all(mode == 2)],  by = cols]$V1
df2[i1]
#   col1 col2 mode
#1:    1    2    1
#2:    1    2    1
#3:    4    1    3
#4:    4    1    2
#5:    4    1    2

df2[!i1]
#   col1 col2 mode
#1:    1    3    5
#2:    5    3    9
#3:    3    2    2
#4:    3    2    2
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
i1 <- duplicated(df2[1:2])|duplicated(df2[1:2], fromLast = TRUE)
out11 <- df2[i1 & with(df2, !ave(mode==2, col1, col2, FUN = all)),]
out22 <- df2[setdiff(row.names(df2), row.names(out11)),]
```

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
    col2 = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), mode = c(5L, 
    9L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: it is very slow

Comment: @hghg  I updated with a data.table version.  Hope it is faster for you

Comment: @hghg If we don't specify the column name for `.I[any(mode != 2)]`, by default a column name created is `V1`, which we are extracting

Comment: df1 is a data.table?

Comment: @hghg I converted to data.table with `setDT`

Comment: in df[!i1] I just have data point with mode 2, but it shouldn't be like that

Comment: @hghg I guess you changed the output and input in your post?

Comment: yea, I added more data

Comment: could you plz fix it with new data?

Comment: @hghg Sure, sorry I forgot about this