# Need help turning a column from character to date in R

Tags: r

Im trying to convert a column from character to date.

The current format in the column is "YearMmonth", as in "1990M01".
It is a really weird format, so i'm wondering how R reads this when i use the as.Date code. It is basically "Year Month Month-number". I know how to use the rest of the code, i just need to know how to translate this to R.

I have tried using

```
df <- as.Date(df, "%YM%m", "%Y/%m")

df <- as.Date(paste0("01-", df), format = "%Y/%m/%d")
```

and alot others, the main problem is translating the character column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with the code in the question:

- The first attempt in the question does not have a day field
- the second attempt does but puts the day field first yet the format says it is last.
- the use of `df` in the question suggests that the result is a data frame yet the result is a `Date` class object, not a data frame.

Here are some approaches that work.

### yearmon

Use `as.yearmon` to convert to a `yearmon` object or `as.Date(as.yearmon(...))` to convert to a Date object.  `yearmon` objects directly represent year and month without day so that may be preferable.

```
library(zoo)

as.yearmon("1990M01", "%YM%m")
## [1] "Jan 1990"

as.Date(as.yearmon("1990M01", "%YM%m"))
## [1] "1990-01-01"
```

Replacing the M with a minus would also work:

```
as.yearmon(chartr("M", "-", "1990M01"))
## [1] "Jan 1990"
```

### Base R

A way that does not involve any packages is to append a day:

```
as.Date(paste("1990M01", 1), "%YM%m %d")
## [1] "1990-01-01"
```

or change the M to a minus and append a minus and a  1 in which case it is already in the default format and no format string is needed.

```
as.Date(sub("M(\\d+)", "-\\1-1", "1990M01"))
## [1] "1990-01-01"
```

Comment: I don't know how to send private msg, I made this post and the answers don't work. I do not want to post same question again.could you plz check it and see if you can help? I greatly appreciate it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57934171/how-to-determine-duplicate-rows-where-not-all-are-the-same-in-a-column

Comment: I appreciate your answer! I got the 1990 01 into a date format, but now every date in my column is in that date. How do i change it so that all the original dates in the column are preserved? There are over 1700 entries, so i won't be able to do this for each entry. Basically what i'm asking is how do i turn as.Date(as.yearmon("1990M01", "%YM%m")) into as.Date(as.yearmon("character format", "%YM%m"))

Comment: It works for me.  In fact, I copied and pasted the output from R into the answer.  Try copying the code in the answer into a fresh R session and you should get the same results. If what you mean you did something else then you need to show it in reproducible form so we can know what it is that is causing you errors.  There are no "columns" in the question; howver, if you did give it a vector of character strings then all the answers are already vectorized.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me too! I may have formulated the question badly, let me try again.

Comment: I have a column with 1700 dates ranging from "1990M01" all the way to "2007M03". I need to convert all of them (with their original dates) into a date format. if i use the code you submitted, i only have january 1990 in all of the entries, rather than their original dates. Thank you for helping me through this!

Comment: You likely forgot to substitute the date with the column name. Try this. `DF <- data.frame(date = c("1900M01", "1900M02")); transform(DF, date = as.Date(paste(date, 1), "%YM%m %d"))`  No te that there is a space after the `m`.

Comment: Of course, how stupid of me... It all works now! Thank you so much for your help!